# How to get average of all items after $group, per year?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have created a MongoDB aggregate pipeline. I am grouping my data by room and year getting the results below. However, I want to get the average for any room per year. In other words, **I want to get the average room transaction revenue group by years.**

Here is my pipeline:

```
let pipeline = [
 {
  "$group" : {
    "_id" : { "room" : "$room", "year" : "$year"},
    "total_revs" : { "$sum" : 1 },
    "average_stay" : { "$avg" : { "$subtract": ["$endDate", "$startDate"]}},
    "average_leadtime"     : { "$avg" : { "$subtract": ["$startDate", "$orderDate"]}},
    "average_party_size"   : { "$avg" : "$numberOfPeople" },
    "transaction_revenue"  : { "$avg": "$tranFee" }
  }
}  
]

let promise = HReservation.aggregate(pipeline).exec();
promise.then(result => res.send(result))
.catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));
```

This pipeline produces the following results:

```
[
{
    "_id": {
        "year": 2013
    },
    "total_revs": 66100,
    "average_stay": 233698275.34039333,
    "average_leadtime": 6089703358.547655,
    "average_party_size": null,
    "transaction_revenue": 10.53087821482602
},
{
    "_id": {
        "year": 2012
    },
    "total_revs": 60936,
    "average_stay": 235630563.21386373,
    "average_leadtime": 6001076644.348168,
    "average_party_size": null,
    "transaction_revenue": 10.534949947485886
},
{
    "_id": {
        "year": 2010
    },
    "total_revs": 50492,
    "average_stay": 241539095.3022261,
    "average_leadtime": 6193156175.235681,
    "average_party_size": null,
    "transaction_revenue": 10.506802463756634
},
{
    "_id": {
        "year": 2015
    },
    "total_revs": 81832,
    "average_stay": 229180877.89617753,
    "average_leadtime": 6365565822.661061,
    "average_party_size": null,
    "transaction_revenue": 10.7106377700655
}
]
```

***Problem:***

This is just telling me the roughly what the transaction cost is per transaction...$10 with some slight deviations in the data.

I need the sum of those averages...per year. I think I'm phrasing that correctly.

Desired result: I want to get the average total room transaction revenue for each year.

How can achieve my desired results?

Answer (score 0):

I was projecting my room id incorrectly into my first `$group` stage. Once I was able to group correctly, the final `$group` was the obvious answer.

```
                {
                    "$group" : {
                        "_id" : {"room": "$room", "year": "$year"},
                        "total_revs" : { "$sum" : 1 },
                        "average_stay"         : { "$avg" : { "$subtract": ["$endDate", "$startDate"]}},
                        "average_leadtime"     : { "$avg" : { "$subtract": ["$startDate", "$orderDate"]}},
                        "transaction_revenue"   : { "$sum" : "$tranFee" }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$group" : {
                        "_id" : "$_id.year",
                        "average_tr" : { "$avg" : "$transaction_revenue" }
                    }
                }
```